# How to put a "cancel registration" link in an email

Tags: email, hyperlink, registration, cancel-button

I'm working on a registration system that sends a confirmation email after a user registers for an event. I'd like to include a link in that email that allows them to cancel their registration. Is there an easy/standard way to do this?

Comment: what are you writing your app in or are you using a service like MailChimp? We need a little more information to help you.

Comment: Which part are you asking about? Actually putting a link in an email, or the back end implementation of the page that link points to?

Comment: I can/will figure out how to remove a registration on the back end. What I don't know how to do, is how to provide a link that will give our server the information it needs to know who to remove. Maybe I should just spend more time figuring out how these mails get sent out (and the possibility that that service has a standard way of doing this).